# Django REST framework 2 example not working

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm working the very first example of the [Django REST framework](http://www.tomchristie.com/rest-framework-2-docs/) (version 2).  I've followed the Installation and Example instructions to the letter but when I open the API in my browser at http://127.0.0.1:8000/ per their instructions, I get the error shown below.  What am I doing wrong?  This example seems pretty elementary.

```
    Page not found (404)
    Request Method: GET
    Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
    Using the URLconf defined in conf.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

    ^admin/
    ^api-auth/
    The current URL, , didn't match any of these.
```

Comment: What version of Django are you using? I just publish a possible answer (assuming you're using Django 2.x) hope it helps.

Comment: I'm using Django 1.84 (which is why I'm using version 2 of the framework).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Django 2.x for following that tutorial, I'm afraid it's not updated. I just did exactly what the tutorial says, and in the first try it fails.

Then, I changed my urls.py file as follow:

before:

```
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path(r'^api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')),
    path(r'^', include(router.urls)),
```

After:

```
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')),
    path('', include(router.urls)),
```

and then did `python manage.py runserver`, and it's working properly.

Answer (score 0):

you don't have a main url defined, must define a index url something like this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('index', views.index, name='index'),

    # the next path cath the empty path url www.example.com
    re_path('/?$', views.index)
]
```

the url `http://127.0.0.1:8000/` don't exist in your urlpatterns, that's what django is telling you.

to work in django rest framework you must follow the next flowjob:

- create yours models
- create a serializer for yours models
- create a ApiView, ViewSet or Django view where you use your serializers to respond to user requests.
- register your views in you urlpattern

if you want to enter in the rest-framework login URLs use the path`localhost:8000/api-auth`